# uploading files with multer is not working for express.js app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, express, multer

I have a simple blog app with Express.js in the back-end and React.js in the front-end. I am trying to add a feature to add pictures to the postgres database and my schema looks like this.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS learningtable (
     id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     topstuff VARCHAR(255),
     bottomstuff VARCHAR(255),
     pic1 bytea
     );
```

My upload form looks like this.

```
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
      <input type="text" name="topstuff" placeholder="top" onChange={this.handleTopChange} value={this.state.inputTopValue} /> <br/>
      <input type="text" name="bottomstuff" placeholder="bottomt" onChange={this.handleBottomChange} value={this.state.inputBottomValue} /><br/>
      <input type="file" name="pic1" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="yeah boy" />
    </form>
```

My router file looks like this

```
    const express = require('express');
    const myrouter = express.Router();
    const controller = require('../controllers/learningController');
    const multer = require('multer');

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
       },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
         }
       })

   var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

   myrouter.post('/', upload.single('pic1'), controller.create);

   module.exports = myrouter;
```

My controller is

```
     const controller = {};            

     controller.create = (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body);
     console.log(req.file)
      LearningObject.create({
        topstuff: req.body.topstuff,
        bottomstuff: req.body.bottomstuff,
        pic1: req.file,
      })
       .then(jsonAfterAdding => {
         res.json({
          message: 'okay',
          jsonAfterAdding: jsonAfterAdding
       });
       }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
            res.status(400).json(err);
                });
             };

    module.exports = controller;
```

And my model looks like this

```
    const db = require('../db/config');
    const LearningObject = {};

    LearningObject.create = (blahblah) => {
      return db.one (
        `INSERT INTO learningtable
         (topstuff, bottomstuff, pic1)
         VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *
       `,
      [blahblah.topstuff, blahblah.bottomstuff, blahblah.pic1]
      );
     };


     module.exports = LearningObject;
```

When I console log req.file after trying to upload it says its undefined. The texts, "topstuff" and "bottomstuff" get saved to the database but I do not see the picture in the folder or the database.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this in html file

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} action='/' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <input type="text" name="topstuff" placeholder="top" onChange={this.handleTopChange} value={this.state.inputTopValue} /> <br/>
      <input type="text" name="bottomstuff" placeholder="bottomt" onChange={this.handleBottomChange} value={this.state.inputBottomValue} /><br/>
      <input type="file" name="pic1" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="yeah boy" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi, it didnt work and gave me the same error. The other two texts get sent to the database but the picture I dont see.in the folder.